# Why doesn't the location of a function expression matter in node js?

Tags: javascript, hoisting, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

In JavaScript, when using a function expression (e.g. `var myFunc = function() {...}`), like any other variable declaration, you have to define the variable **before** using it. For example, the following example will **not** work (will result in `Uncaught TypeError: myFunc is not a function`):

```
var myVar = myFunc();

var myFunc = function() {
    // code here...
}
```

However, in my routes/index.js file of a node js project, I have the following code (abbreviated obviously):

```
var router = express.Router();
.
.
.
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    ...
    ...
    var myVar = myFunc(); // WORKS!
    ...
    ...
}

var myFunc = function() {
    ...
}
```

The `myFunc` variable is declared **after** it is used, so shouldn't this throw an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects to this:

1. Why can the callback passed to `router.post` access the `myFunc` variable, when the variable declaration is *below* it in the code?
2. Why can the callback passed to `router.post` access the function assigned to the `myFunc` variable, when it's not assigned to the variable until *below* it in the code?

First we'll deal with the variable, then we'll deal with its value (the function we assign to it):

> The myFunc variable is declared after it is used, so shouldn't this throw an error?

It would if `var` weren't hoisted. But `var` is hoisted. So when your module is loaded, *first* the JavaScript engine looks through it to find all variable declarations and function declarations, processes those, and *then* does the step-by-step code in your module.

E.g., to the JavaScript engine, your module actually looks like this:

```
var router = undefined;
var myFunc = undefined;

router = express.Router();
.
.
.
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var myVar = undefined;
    ...
    ...
    myVar = myFunc(); // WORKS!
    ...
    ...
}

myFunc = function() {
    ...
}
```

More on this on my anemic little blog: [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

> Why doesn't the location of a function expression matter in node js?

It **does**. The only reason you're not running into trouble is that `myFunc` isn't used until the *callback* you're passing into `router.post` is called, which is *after* the top-level scope code of your module script has been run (including the expression creating `myFunc`).

E.g., what happens is:

1. The prep stuff (creating the vars `router` and `myFunc` and setting them to `undefined`)
2. The `express.Router` call, which assigns a new value to `router`
3. The call to `router.post`, passing in *but not calling* a callback function
4. Creation of the function, which assigns a new value to `myFunc`
5. Later, when a request comes in, the callback is called, by which time `myFunc` has been created (and is accessible because the callback is a closure over the context where `myFunc` is declared)

This is analogous to this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var myVar = myFunc();
}, 0);

var myFunc = function() {
    // code here...
}
```

First `setTimeout` is called, then the function is created and assigned to `myFunc`, then later the callback function is called and calls the function via `myFunc`.

Comment: So are you stating that all var are hoisted or are you saying that vars that are defined in a function callback are?

Comment: @jrock2004: All variables are hoisted to the top of their respective scope.

Comment: @jrock2004: All `var` declarations are processed upon entry to the function (or global) scope where they appear. This is not true of `let` or `const` declarations (ES2015+). More on my anemic little blog: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html

Comment: Makes sense - thank you! (downvoter, please explain yourself)